# Get case-insensitive collation of column

Tags: sql-server, collation

I need to perform a case-insensitive query in SQL Server. This can be trivially achieved by converting everything to uppercase or lowercase:

```
SELECT id
FROM Persons
WHERE UPPER(name) = UPPER(@name)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693921/1149773) indicates that using `collate` can be drastically more efficient:

```
SELECT id
FROM Persons
WHERE name = @name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

However, as pointed out [by gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3620520/1149773), the above query assumes that the column's original collation was Latin1-compatible, and may break if the column's collation is changed in the future.

Is there a way of forcing an expression to use the case-insensitive version of the column's current collation, whatever it happens to be? Wishfully:

```
SELECT id
FROM Persons
WHERE name = @name collate *_CI
```

I'm aware this can be achieved using dynamic SQL, but would prefer not to go down that route.

Comment: 99% of sql server installs are case insensitive. So a better option is do the norm and then apply case sensitivity via explicit collation in the few cases where it might be needed. (In fact, the only installs of SQL Server I've seen where they were not case insensitive, they had been set up incorrectly)...And no, you can't do what you want without dynamic TSQL

Comment: @MitchWheat: That's been my experience too, but I've run into case-sensitive columns on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer while testing [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/445704/567459/badge-order-received?BadgeName=C%23&BadgeClass=Gold). I don't want to be bound by a fixed CI collation since Stack Overflow might change their collation in the future. UPPER(x) = UPPER(y) presently seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: what is SEDE? are you saying the Stack Exchange Database uses case sensitive collation? That would be a fail IMO! You can always change it if you have restored locally: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175835.aspx

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment to expand the acronym. My former query doesn't return results, but its [lowercase counterpart](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/445704/567459/badge-order-received?BadgeName=c%23&BadgeClass=Gold) does. (I've since [fixed it](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445704/badge-order-received) to convert everything to lowercase.)